# Java 8+ API desugaring support for pure kotlin modules

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, android-r8

I'm trying new [Java 8+ API desugaring support (Android Gradle Plugin 4.0.0+)](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring)

Everything is fine with android app and android library modules but in pure kotlin modules desugared API's get highlighted red with errors similar to:

> Call requires API level 26 (current min is 21):
>   java.time.LocalTime#parse

Everything compiles and works well.

Is there something in .gradle file that needs to be specified or is it a bug in IDE?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be [a known bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/158189490) on the google issue tracker